# keeping default encoding type upon writing lines

Tags: powershell

I am using the following script to delete the last line of a file, the problem is that it seems to be changing the encoding type of the file to something else which makes characters such pound (£) signs unreadable.

```
$path = "D:\Test\"
$filter =  "*.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem -path $path -filter $filter

foreach ($item in $files) {
    Write-Host "Start Processing "  $item.FullName -foregroundcolor "green"

    # Read all lines
    $LinesInFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($item.FullName)
    # Write all lines, except for the last one, back to the file
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($item.FullName,$LinesInFile[0..($LinesInFile.Count - 2)])
    # Clean up
    Remove-Variable -Name LinesInFile

    Write-Host "Ended Processing "  $item.FullName -foregroundcolor "white"
}
```

I tried setting the encoding type upon writing files to "ANSI" which seems to be the default encoding type of the files, however, nothing happens.

> Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($item.FullName,$LinesInFile[0..($LinesInFile.Count - 2)],  Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have characters like that I'd recommend setting the encoding to UTF-8 or Unicode. I'd also recommend using PowerShell cmdlets instead of .NET methods if you're processing your files line-by-line anyway.

```
foreach ($item in $files) {
    $path = $item.FullName

    Write-Host "Start Processing $path" -ForegroundColor 'green'

    $LinesInFile = Get-Content $path
    $LinesInFile[0..($LinesInFile.Count - 2)] | Set-Content $path -Encoding UTF8

    Write-Host "Ended Processing $path" -ForegroundColor 'white'
}
```

**Edit:** If performance is an issue you could use a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in combination with a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for reading/writing the data.

```
$path   = 'D:\Test'
$filter = '*.txt'
$files  = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter

$encoding = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)

# ring buffer size (== number of lines to remove from end of file)
$bufferSize = 2

$tempFile = Join-Path $path 'temp.txt'

foreach ($item in $files) {
  # create ring buffer
  $buffer  = New-Object Object[] $bufferSize
  $current = 0

  $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader ($item.FullName, $encoding)
  $writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($tempFile, $false, $encoding)

  while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
    if ($buffer[$current]) {
      $writer.WriteLine($buffer[$current])
    }
    $buffer[$current] = $reader.ReadLine()
    $current = ($current + 1) % $bufferSize
  }

  $reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
  $writer.Close(); $writer.Dispose()

  Remove-Item $item.FullName -Force
  Rename-Item $tempFile $item.Name
}
```

Comment: Problem is, my files are 1gb+ and using get-content takes forever

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I tried your script, however, the encoding type of the files should be kept as ansi, but now with your script they are all utf-8 and the pound sign is still unreadable. PS. my files are in ansi, my original script processes them file and writes them as ansi, however, there is a file which contains rows with a £ sign (pound) and somehow the script is turning the encoding of this particular file alone to utf-8 with bom, how can I set my script to read the file as ansi and write the it as ansi.

Comment: @J.D Like I said, you can create both reader and writer with the desired encoding. `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8` is just an example. You can change that to `windows-1252` encoding by replacing it with `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)`. See updated answer.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I needed to export that last line to a different file so I used the `tail` parameter to do it,  this is working fine for me here is the screenshot (http://i.imgur.com/XLwUHRR.png)  `get-content $item.Fullname -tail 1 | Out-File -Encoding Ascii $path\"trailer-"$item` do you suggest anything regarding this? it works absolutely fine, but you may have a recommendation.

Comment: @J.D Please avoid scope creep. If you have a new question: post a new question.